# Replace vector inside of map

Tags: clojure

I have a vector of maps which looks like this

```
[{:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [vector]}
 {:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [vector]}]
```

In other words, a vector of n maps, with one of the keys also being a vector.

I want to replace the :key3 vector with a new vector, in all the n maps in the outer vector, but I can't figure out a good way to do this.

As a bonus question, I also want to create a new map with the same structure, but with the inner vector containing a chosen range of elements. So for example from this

```
[{:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [v1 v2 v3 v4]}
 {:key1 val2 :key2 val2 :key3 [v1 v2 v3 v4]}]
```

to this:

```
[{:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [v2 v3]}
 {:key1 val2 :key2 val2 :key3 [v2 v3]}]
```

In other words picking out a range of elements from the internal vector while keeping the data structure otherwise intact.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(def m [{:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [:a :b :c :d]}
        {:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [:a :b :c :d]}])

(mapv #(update % :key3 (fn [v] (mapv v [1 2]))) m)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapv` to map over the elements of the vector, update `:key3` using `update-in` then do another `mapv` on the vector to extract the indices you want:

```
(def m [{:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [:a :b :c :d]}
        {:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [:a :b :c :d]}])

(mapv #(update-in % [:key3] (fn [v] (mapv v [1 2]))) m)
```

Answer (score 0):

For many data manipulations, the core functions like `update-in` and mapv do a good job on this kind of problem. There are several ways to use them subtly wrong and get back a sequence instead of a vector. The code can get a tad unwieldily as well sometimes.

The [spectre](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) library was created to make this kind of data manipulation easy and intuative:

```
hello.core> (require '[com.rpl.specter :refer :all])
nil

hello.core> (def data '[{:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [vector]}
                        {:key1 val1 :key2 val2 :key3 [vector]}])
#'hello.core/data

hello.core> (setval [ALL :key3] '[v2 v3] data)
[{:key1 val1, :key2 val2, :key3 [v2 v3]} 
 {:key1 val1, :key2 val2, :key3 [v2 v3]}]
```

It also tries to use the most efficient update method for each transformation. 
This [article](http://nathanmarz.com/blog/clojures-missing-piece.html) gives a more complete (and opinionated) introduction.